# What do you call the shape of a log-normal distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Normal distributions form "bell curves", sine waves form "sinusoids", logistic functions form "sigmoids"... what do log-normal distributions form?

Comment: I don't know that there is a special name for this curve other than "the pdf of a log-normal distribution".

Comment: A nomenclature based on shape rather than functional form can be quite broad.  For instance, [sigmoid functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples) include members well beyond the logistic function.  In that sense, I am not sure how helpful these names are more generally.  I suppose I may refer to a log-normal distribution as right-skewed among other features.

Comment: Yeah, the broad shape is exactly why I ask. I have data that fits this _shape_, but is not generated from a log-normal distribution. So the slide with the chart appears on screen, and I say "as you can see, the data form a ......".